# Unknown systemd call to weirf-like command

Tags: systemd

Just wanted your lights to understand something as much as i can.

Some days ago i have noticed a weird command running which i don't quite remember it's name at the moment but what i do remember is it's parent process which was something like:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
```

as far as i can recall.

Systemd is linux's Services Manager and for some reason invoked with the above arguments the above call.

Unfortunately i cannot recall the actual command which was being invoked at the moment but i do remember the call to that weird command. Actually this call comes and go occasionally at arbitrary intervals. 3-4 times os so.

I googled a bit , but it seems there is no intrinsic information regarding to that systemd call. Intentionally undocumented ystem call some post mentioned.

Can someone shed some light into this, as to how can i investigate this any further?

Answer (score 0):

You need no investigation for normal, expected behaviour.

> --switched-root --system --deserialize 22

That translates to "Systemd switched roots (i.e from the initrd to the live running system), it is a --system instance and it wanted to restore its state from open file descriptor number 22 "